# Problem with appending data to table from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to append data to table from the firebase database. But all table data come under one `<td>` element.

I've tried different code snippets relevant to this issue. but couldn't find a better solution

Here is my code.

```
var dbRefUsers = firebase.database().ref().child('Web App').child('Users');

  dbRefUsers.on('value', gotData, errData); 

 function gotData(data){

    var users = data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(users)



    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        var k = keys[i];

        var userName = users[k].Name;
        var userEmail = users[k].Email;
        var userPassword = users[k].Password;


    console.log(userName, userEmail, userPassword);


   var appendingTo = document.getElementById("userlist");
   var tr = document.createElement('tr');
   tr.append(userName, userEmail, userPassword);
    appendingTo.appendChild(tr);

    }
 }

 function errData(error){
    console.log("Error!")
    console.log(error);
```

Actually, I need this data, append into separate 3 `<td>` element under one `<tr>` element. Could anyone please help with my concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't create any `td` elements. Since that is not legal HTML, the browser creates a single `td` element for you and puts all text in it. If you want control over the `td` elements, you should create them in your code.

Something like this function is helpful for that:

```
function createElementWithText(tag, text) {
  var elm = document.createElement(tag);
  elm.textContent = text;
  return elm;
}
```

And then:

```
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userName));
tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userEmail));
tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userPassword));
appendingTo.appendChild(tr);
```

Or with `append` as you were already using:

```
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
tr.append(createElementWithText('td', userName), createElementWithText('td', userEmail), createElementWithText('td', userPassword));
appendingTo.appendChild(tr);
```

Comment: I've tried both methods provided by you. but in the chrome console, same error occurred shown below.

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('John Mark') is not a valid name.

So how could I fix it?

Comment: Woops, good catch. I forgot to pass in the tag name to the new function. Added that now.